# ¿Por qué el ciclo for itera en desorden una lista?

Tags: python, lista, pandas, bucle-for

Quiero hacer un filtro booleano a un DataFrame y necesito hacer esto día a día y en orden.

```
Month = {'01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'}
Day = {'01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12',..., '31'}
for dtm in Month:
    for dtd in Day:
        Max_T.append(df_Tmax.Data_Value[(df_Tmax.Month == dtm) & (df_Tmax.Day == dtd)].max())
```

Comment: La "lista" no es una lista, es un conjunto (set)... y los conjuntos por definición no tienen orden. `Month = [...]` y `Day = [...]` no `Month = {...}` y `Day = {...}`. Posiblemente no necesites el for y se pueda vectorizar, pero sería bueno que agregaras un [mcve] con un DF de partida y el esperado de salida.

Comment: utilicé el set(Day) para eliminar los valores repetidos, como convierto eso de nuevo a una lista

Comment: En el momento que aplicas set se va a tomar viento el orde ¿De dónde proviene Day? ¿Te quedarías  con la primera aparición o la última de un día repetido? ¿El orden depende del orden original o sin importar éste el reultado final sería los dias ordenados?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si partimos de `Day = ["02", "05", "01", "05"]` ¿el resultado sería `["01", "02", "05"]` (eliminamos duplicados y ordenamos)  o `["02", "05", "01"]` (nos quedamos con el primer duplicado) o `["02", "01", "05"]` (nos quedamos con el último duplicado)?